# How to run javascript load bar function if runtime of PHP/MySQL queries is too long?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have looked around and can't see that this question has been asked before now.

I have a sign-up page where the loading is a bit slow. I want to create a function that shows a gif file of a load bar if the runtime of the sign-up is greater than X amount of time.

I was thinking about Javascript/AJAX to create the function but I can't code it as my Javascript knowledge doesn't stretch that far yet.

Question: How to call a Javascript function when load time of a page is greater than X?

Comment: It might be worth trying to make your sign-up page load faster instead, if it’s slower than the rest of the pages and you don’t know why.

Comment: Are you fetching the data from the back-end (PHP) via Ajax (XMLHttpRequest)?

Comment: No, i am not fetching my data via AJAX. I figured out while i was at the WC, that it is the PHPMailer that is the issue and that I should use The AJAX GET request for that one. But it would still be interesting to learn how to do as I described in my post.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my own question was to create an ajax get request and while the page was processing the request I simply showed a gif file (load bar). When the request was finished and the response was ready I redirected it to an other page with `window.location.href = "newpage.html"`